# ¿Cómo almacenar datos recibidos por Bluetooth en un Array en Android Studio para poder operar con ellos?

Tags: java, android-studio, arduino, bluetooth

buenas.

Arduino lee los valores de un sensor cada cierto tiempo y los envía por bluetooth, la aplicación los recibe y debe almacenarlos en un array para operar posteriormente con ellos.

Mi duda es sobre como realizar esto último.

Esta parte de código es la que obtiene los datos y los envía a otra clase

```
        final Intent intent = new Intent(action);
        Log.v("AndroidLE", "broadcastUpdate()");
        final byte[] data = characteristic.getValue();
        //Log.v("AndroidLE", "data.length: " + data.length);

        if (data != null && data.length > 0) {
            final StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(data.length);
              for(byte byteChar : data) {
                  stringBuilder.append(String.format("%02X ", byteChar));
                //Log.v("AndroidLE", String.format("%02X ", byteChar));
            }

            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DATA, new String(data) + "\n" + stringBuilder.toString());
            Log.v("AndroidLE", new String(data));
            Log.v("AndroidLE", stringBuilder.toString());
            //intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DATA, new String(data));
            //intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DATA, stringBuilder.toString());
        }

        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
```

Los datos se ven de la siguiente forma en ambos formatos

```
2020-10-18 14:27:07.434 32292-32292 V/AndroidLE: 415
    419
    418
    418
    
    34 31 35 0D 0A 34 31 39 0D 0A 34 31 38 0D 0A 34 31 38 0D 0A 
2020-10-18 14:27:07.446 32292-32339 V/AndroidLE: broadcastUpdate()
2020-10-18 14:27:07.448 32292-32339 V/AndroidLE: 417
    417
2020-10-18 14:27:07.449 32292-32339 V/AndroidLE: 34 31 37 0D 0A 34 31 37
```

Aquí los recibo e invoco a la función que debería almacenarlos

```
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            final String action = intent.getAction();
            if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED.equals(action)) {
                updateConnectionState(true);
            } else if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED.equals(action)) {
                updateConnectionState(false);
                clearUI();
            } else if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {
                // Show all the supported services and characteristics on the user interface.
                connect_caracterist_ard(mBluetoothLeService.getSupportedGattServices());
            } else if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE.equals(action)) {
                guarda_array(intent.getStringExtra(BluetoothLeService.EXTRA_DATA));
            }
        }
    };
```

Alguna idea de como realizar esta función de guardado, no se muy bien como almacenar cada valor en una celda del array y si debería convertirlos a int una vez guardados o antes de hacerlo.

Tal vez debería de modificar el formado de data en broadcastUpdate pero no entiendo muy bien como realizar esto.

Muchas gracias.